# Result of Reduce contains duplicate terms

Tags: equation-solving

On my system, the result of this:

```
f[x_] := 2 Sin[x] + Sin[x]^2;
Reduce[f'[x] == 0, x]
```

contains the following expression twice:

```
x == -(Pi/2) + 2*Pi*C[1]
```

This is the entire result:

```
Element[C[1], Integers] && 
     (x == -(Pi/2) + 2*Pi*C[1] || x == Pi/2 + 2*Pi*C[1] || 
      x == -(Pi/2) + 2*Pi*C[1] || x == (3*Pi)/2 + 2*Pi*C[1])
```

Is there a reason the expression appears twice? Is this a bug?

Comment: My guess is that this is because `x == -(\[Pi]/2) + 2 \[Pi] C[1]` is a double root of `f'[x]`.

Comment: Though written in an unusual way, I'd like to note that the result is correct.  It'd be simpler to write is as $(k+\frac{1}{2})\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Heike seems to have got it (try plotting your derivative, and note the behavior at crossings). In general for trigonometric functions, it vastly helps to confine your attention to a single period: `Reduce[f'[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to sum up here the answers given so far in comments:

- if you work in a single period, you get the expected results:

  ```
  In:=  Reduce[f'[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]
  Out=  x == \[Pi]/2 || x == (3 \[Pi])/2
  ```
- if you work on the whole real domain, you can get the expression to be reduced by using `Simplify`:

  ```
  In:=  Simplify[Reduce[f'[x] == 0, x]]
  Out=  C[1] \[Element] Integers && (\[Pi] + 2 x == 4 \[Pi] C[1] || \[Pi] + 4 \[Pi] C[1] == 2 x || 2 x == \[Pi] (3 + 4 C[1]))
  ```
- the reason why you get one of the elements twice in the first place is that it's a double root.

Comment: For more complex expressions, often applying `LogicalExpand` to the results from `Reduce` before using `Simplify` will yield better results than just `Simplify` alone.